# Install order: Sharepoint ajax and .NET 3.5 ajax

Tags: .net, sharepoint, .net-3.5, asp.net-ajax, sharepoint-2007

As far as I know Sharepoint 2007 uses ASP.NET Ajax 1.0 with System.Web.Extensions 1.0 while I'm creating webparts with VS2008 SP1 and .NET 3.5 SP1 which includes System.Web.Extensions 3.5.

So what is the order of installation and how do you install to get both versions working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are developing web parts using 3.5 SP1 and deploying them to SP2007 without any issues. Simply installing 3.5 SP1 on the SP2007 server should cover you.